# Какую функцию выполняет - Normalize.css?

Tags: css, css3, sass, scss

Какую функцию выполняет - Normalize.css ? Везде написано что используется для :

> 1: обеспечения HTML-элементов лучшую кроссбраузерность
>
> ---
>
> 2: при помощи которого браузеры начинают отображать все элементы более
>   последовательно и в соответствии с современными стандартами.

Но есть возражения, по следующим пунктам:

**По первому** пункту -  Зачем он нужен , когда есть `gulp-autoprefixer`, который как раз и обеспечивает кросбраузерность элементов стиля.

**По второму** пункту ничего не понятно, что второй пункт значит и что конкретно делает эта программа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В каждом браузере есть свой собственный набор стилей для html-элементов, задающий то, как они будут отображаться "по умолчанию"(user agent style), без их переопределения.

Проблема состоит в том, что везде они разные - где-то margin/pading другие, где-то у элемента рисуется граница, а где-то и вообще размер и гарнитура шрифта другая.

Каждый раз при верстке помнить об всех этих мелочах, и обязательно переопределять их - можно замучатся. И тут на помощь приходит `Normalize.css - он приводит стили "по умолчанию" в браузерах к единому знаменателю, что собственно в итоге упрощает кроссбраузерную верстку.

Если интересно - можете заглянуть в [неминимизированный код Normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css), и почитать какие различия в каких браузерах он исправляет.

`autoprefixer`(в том числе и в gulp), в свою очередь, выполняет совсем другую задачу - он позволяет не писать [префиксы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) у требующих их правил - он самостоятельно подставляет их, на этапе сборки проекта. Это слегка упрощает написание CSS-стилей, но никак не помогает в обеспечении кросбраузерности верстки.

Comment: О, Спасибо) А можно еще вопросик по сопутствующий тематике? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484958/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2