# Базовые стили браузеров

Tags: css

Какое решение в настоящий момент времени популярно, для нормализации (приведение всех стилей браузеров, к общему единому состоянию) базовых стилей браузеров, в процессе разработки проекта?

Пока я нашел три решения:

1. Сделать все самому, что бы точно знать как все будет устроено.
2. Использовать - normalize.css
3. Использовать - reset.css

Еще, я обратил внимание на некоторые сайты крупных проектов, и заметил, что  они, не используют 2 и 3 вариант.

Comment: Мне больше всего по душе `compass/reset` + свой сброс, например, убрать аутлайны, изменить цвет ссылок и т.д. и т.п.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Согласен с Oceinic , все уже есть в популярных фреймах, да и вообще браузеры уже давно стали придерживаться единых стандартов, хотя бы стремятся.
А по существу отвечу, что 2 и 3 пункты очень стоит применять:

- если будут векторы, шрифты и svg всякие.
- если верстка под мобильные браузеры.

Тут важно понять чего вы хотите добиться. Вообще сбросы CSS отменяют стили агента пользователя и возвращают множество элементов к их «обесстиленному» состоянию, некому ровному основанию, на котором можно безопасно строить. Однако затем нужно назначить стили большей части элементов до того, как вы сможете строить с их помощью. Задайтесь вопросами: 
- Оно вам надо? 
- Вы делаете свой bootstrap?
Нет? Тогда используйте готовые фреймы, это очень сэкономит вам нервы и время.

Comment: Для векторной графики aka SVG есть свой фреймворк - Raphael. По поводу мобильной верстки: Bootstrap называет себя mobile-first

Comment: @Oceinic согласен с примерами, более того Bootstrap можно не только готовый брать, с его стилистикой, а можно скачать кастомный со всеми необходимыми настройками, у него есть мастер кастомизации на сайте

Answer (score 6):

С нуля было актуально делать несколько лет назад, когда интернет был медленнее, а CSS3 только вышел.
После появления CSS3 разработчики, которым чем-то неподходила функциональность "из коробки", как это обычно бывает, стали выкладывать сниппеты, рещающие разнообразные проблемы. Так появились нормалайзеры и резеты. Некоторые из этих сниппетов позже были объединены в фреймворки. Так появились Bootstrap и Foundation.
Я не вижу причин использовать нормалайзер не из состава какого-нибудь фреймворка. Даже если вам нужен только нормалайзер и не нужно ничего больше.
Например, чтобы получить Bootstrap4 состоящий из одного только нормалайзера, достаточно закомментировать лишние строки в файле [bootstrap.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/bootstrap.scss) и перекомпилировать репозиторий.

Answer (score 5):

Лично использую ресет.

так как видел на примере сброс распростростроненных стилей к одному. + js подгрузку(если браузер неподдеживает css3 например ;)

Также в довесок добавлю, это требует меньше написания в css, и далее можно спокойно работать от одного старта для всех браузеров.

и как уже было сказано крупные проекты используют именно ресет. а не переделкой бутстрапа или иного каркаса(хотя и его подгрузить полностью легче и нетрогать)

Нормализация после сброса используется если у пользователей ну  уж слишкой большой разброс в браузерах(чаще всего в версиях а не в названиях) Так как старенькая опера и новенькая это как старый ие и хром, со своими особенностями и более близкий к нормам хтмл.

резюмируя, советую использовать reset.css + jquery ui + shiv.js для хоршего старта в html5 + css3

Answer (score 3):

Лично я использую первый способ. 
Но еще рекомендую обратить внимание: в этой статье https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/64 понятно описываются отличия reset.css от normalize.css (важно это понимать)

Comment: Старайтесь писать ответ более содержательно, а ссылку приводить, как дополнение.

Comment: @Елена Краснорядцева - Да, кстати, а почему Вы используете первый способ?